# Question of category of rings

Tags: ring-theory, category-theory

How to verify that $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2],$ with the evident morphisms satisfies the universal property for the coproduct of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ in the category of commutative rings. Further why it does not satisfy it in the category of Rings.

Comment: Does your category of [commutative] rings require your [commutative] rings to have $1$ and that morphisms send $1$ to $1$?

Comment: @Stahl, yeah it does.

Comment: You can't verify that since it isn't true. $ℤ$ is the initial object in Ring and CRing, and you can check that the coproduct of inital objects is again the initial object. (You can look at this as a special case of associativity, since the initial object is the coproduct of zero objects.)
$ℤ[x, y]$ is instead the coproduct in CRing of two copies of $ℤ[x]$, or more conveniently put, of $ℤ[x]$ and $ℤ[y]$.
An unnecessarily lengthy, but very instructive way to prove this is to show that coproduct in CRing is the tensor product, that $R ⊗ ℤ[X] ≅ R[X]$, and of course that $ℤ[x][y] ≅ ℤ[x, y]$.

Comment: @user54748, thank you. I'll check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using the yoneda lemma

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{CRing}(\mathbb{Z}[x] \amalg \mathbb{Z}[y], R) &\cong \mathbf{CRing}(\mathbb{Z}[x], R) \times \mathbf{CRing}(\mathbb{Z}[y], R)
\\&\cong R \times R \cong R^2
\\&\cong \mathbf{CRing}(\mathbb{Z}[x,y] , R)
\end{align}$$

So the yoneda lemma says $\mathbb{Z}[x] \amalg \mathbb{Z}[y] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$.

#### Using free rings

If $F$ is the free ring functor, then

$$ \mathbb{Z}[x,y] \cong F(\{x, y \}) \cong F(\{x\} \amalg \{y\}) \cong F(\{x\}) \amalg F(\{y\}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[x] \amalg \mathbb{Z}[y] $$

The free ring functor preserves coproducts (in fact, *all* colimits) because it is a left adjoint. (its right adjoint is the forgetful functor that sends a ring to its set of elements)

#### Noncommutative rings

For noncomutative rings, the problem is that

$$\mathbf{Ring}(\mathbb{Z}[x,y], R) \cong \left\{ (a,b) \in R^2 \mid ab = ba \right\} $$

or equivalently,

$$ \mathbb{Z}[x,y] \cong F(\{x,y\}) / \langle xy - yx \rangle $$

Comment: "Using the Yoneda" and "Using free rings" is the same thing: you just reproduced the proof that left adjoints preserve coproducts.

Comment: @Hurkyl, thank you. I haven't seen Yoneda lemma before. But I'll check.

Answer (score 3):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $r,s \in R$.

By the universal property of polynomial rings, there exist unique ring homomorphisms $f:\mathbb Z[x] \to R$ sending $x$ to $r$ and $g:\mathbb Z[y] \to R$ sending $y$ to $s$. (Remember that since $\mathbb Z$ is initial in rings, we have $f|_{\mathbb Z} = g|_{\mathbb Z}$.)

Let $\iota_x: \mathbb Z[x] \to \mathbb Z[x,y]$ and $\iota_y: \mathbb Z[y] \to \mathbb Z[x,y]$ be the natural inclusions.

Then there exists a ring homomorphism $\varphi: \mathbb Z[x,y] \to R$ sending $x$ to $r$ and $y$ to $s$, uniquely determined by $f$ and $g$:
$$\varphi\left(\sum m_{i, j}x^i y^j\right)=\sum f(m_{i,j})f(x)^i g(y)^j=\sum f(m_{i,j})r^i s^j.$$

So, $\mathbb Z[x,y]$ satisfies the universal property for the coproduct of $\mathbb Z[x]$ and $\mathbb Z[y]$ in the category of commutative rings.

---

If $R$ is not commutative, then there exists $r$ and $s$ in $R$ which do not commute. Therefore, the ring homomorphisms $f$ and $g$ above will be a counterexample to $(i_x, i_y, \mathbb Z[x,y])$ being initial.